# Xcode 5 documentation window missing a full overview of sdk guides and examples

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I am having problem finding SDK guides in new xcode 5. I've downloaded documentation for offline use and when I open new window for xcode documentation there is no way to see a list of all guides and examples like there used to be.

Comment: How exactly are you brining up the documentation? What do you see? Documentation is no longer in the Organizer as it was previously, it is under the Help menu now.

Comment: alt+cmd+shift+? or if I go under help menu and select documentation and api reference. I see a window similar to browser where I can enter searched term and backward/forward buttons. Under there are main document view and left and right sidebar. Left sidebar holds bookmarked pages and right shows the index for currently opened reference or guide. But there is no general overview over all guides and examples like there was on xcode 4 or developer.apple.com ios documentation type.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Ivan, there are lots of issues with Xcode 5 documentation including the one you mentioned. Another example: when you open Xcode documentation `Provide Feedback` link at the bottom doesn't work. And there are lots of broken links throughout Xcode 5 documentation. Best thing is to log a [bug report with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) for each and every issue. I know it takes time to log a bug :( but that's the only way it seems. Hope all the issues will be fixed soon so that developers can work with better productivity.

Comment: Thats weird as it is not working for me :( I have raised a bug (#15048231) as well for this. Also there are a few broken links for me in Xcode 5 documentation. Another frustrating thing is: If you search for any method name in search box and click on right method on search suggestions drop down list, even then Class name for that method will open and not the method itself directly. I can go on and on but let me stop here. I am raising bugs with Apple. There might be others who are facing same issues.

Comment: Indeed there are so many bugs in there like with bookmarks, when I mark any bookmark it only remembers the top page not the section I was referring to.

Comment: There is another interesting observation: if I searched for anything (method name, property, etc) without downloading offline documentation then Xcode documentation search always takes me to the top of the class page which contains that method or property. But then I downloaded iOS doc set for offline use (Xcode Menu --> Preferences --> Downloads) and now when I search for any method or property then am routed directly to method or property and not to the top of the class page. Hurray!!

Answer (score 0):

All documentation you need is under `alt+cmd+shift+?` in Xcode 5 instead of `cmd+shift+2`.

Comment: I know that shortcut before, I've been using it before for the search, but now when it opens you don't have listed all guides like you used to be able to access and browse around them. I have now only option to do search and have a list of results relevant to that search only. Something like on this image [link](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_kvhcnjThqd1qznbjv.png)

Comment: Now if you enter 'core data starting point' top hit is 'audio converter services reference' and the right result comes on 7th place. I tried it on another machine where i have xcode 4 and it returns right search, though I never search for that since i could to frameworks -> coredata and find what I need. They still have old way on their website developer.apple.com so I hope they don't remove it from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the doc online available at:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/

(I hope too that Apple will fix this issue soon)

Comment: Unfortunately that is all what is available at the moment, but it is not a good workflow since I love to have all my documentation offline so I can work on my apps without any internet connection including locally run web service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to also file a bug report about this issue with Apple. This is a step backwards in documentation for Apple. Xcode 4.x was much better for getting to programming guidelines and just finding cool stuff. Now you have to know the method, property you're looking for. Not cool.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Delete the xCode preference files:

```
com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist
com.apple.dt.Xcode.LSSharedFileList.plist
(and any other xCode related files)
```

in ~/Library/Preferences/

and restart xcode.

Comment: Bug appeared again after Maverick update, but the previous solution doesn't work more